# 32bit active perl generating corrupt excel file

Tags: perl, excel-2007, perl-module, activeperl

My code generates an excel 2007 file (.xlsx) from a data structure. 
I am using Excel::Writer::XLSX module to create the excel file and to populate the workbook.

Although the code is working fine with 32bit active perl, while opening the excel, Excel 2007 is throwing error "An attribute value must not contain '<'."

Although the same code when executed using 64bit active perl produces excel without any issue.

Any pointer to what might be the reason will help?

Comment: Compare the files that the two versions of Perl produce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although the same code when executed using 64bit active perl produces excel without any issue.

Based on the error I'd guess that you aren't using the same version of Excel::Writer::XLSX with the 32 and 64 bit ActivePerls.

At the level the warning occurs at the code is pure Perl so there is no binary or 32/64bit issue that would cause this.

I would suggest ensuring that you have updated to the latest version of Excel::Writer::XLSX and testing again.

Also, it looks like the [ActiveState repos for Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) are significantly behind [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) so make sure you upgrade the module from source and not via PPM.

If the issue still occurs then reduce the program down to the smallest amount of working code that demonstrates it and [submit a bug report](http://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-writer-xlsx/issues).

Comment: Yes you are right. The version I was using was 0.53 while the latest is 0.75. Active perl do not have the latest version in ppm. So installed it from source. It fixed the issue. Thank you